How can I search for a text present in a code block in a DM or channel in Slack?
How can I search for a text present in a code block in a DM or channel in Slack? I want to only run the search across code blocks, and not other texts.

Example: in the following screenshot, if I search gradio, I only want to see the first result, and not in the second result. Reason:  gradio is in a code block in the first result, but gradio is not in a code block in the second result.

